# why applyLinearImpulse is not working, using libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I need some help when I try make a game, which is controlled by commands. I need to use textarea and I try to pass the value from textarea to contructer. But my game is not working. I know what mistake is appeared because I call contructer 2 times. I add some code:

```
public class inputs extends Game implements Disposable {
    private Skin skin;
    private Viewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private TextButton button;
    public TextArea TF;
    private Main game;
    public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public inputs(final SpriteBatch sb, final Main game){

        viewport = new FitViewport(1200, 624, new OrthographicCamera());
        stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
        button = new TextButton("Send", skin, "default");
        TF = new TextArea("", skin);

        TF.setWidth(300);
        TF.setHeight(570);
        TF.setPosition(0,54);

        button.setWidth(300);
        button.setHeight(54);
        button.setPosition(0, 0);

        button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
                setScreen(new MainCodeProgram(game,TF.getText(),spriteBatch));
                TF.setText("");
                button.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(TF);
        stage.addActor(button);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
    public void setButtonTouchable(){
        button.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Main.java :

```
public class Main extends Game {
    public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public static int Width = 400;
    public static int Height = 208;
    public static final short objectwhit = 32;
    public static final short mariowhit= 2;
    public static final short itemwhit = 256;
    public static float PPM = 100;
    public static final short marioheadwhit = 512;
    public static final short blockwhit = 4;
    public static final short coinwhit = 8;
    public static final short nothing = 0;
    public static final short ground = 1;
    public static final short destroyedwhit = 16;
    public static final short enemywhit = 64;
    public static final short enemyheadwhit = 128;
    public static inputs inp1;


    @Override
    public void create () {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        inp1 = new inputs(spriteBatch,this);
        setScreen(new MainCodeProgram(this,null,spriteBatch));
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
    }


}
```

Pseudocode recognize :

```
public class MainCodeProgram extends JFrame implements Screen, TextInputListener, Disposable {
    static ArrayList<String> firstintkint = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> firstintvalue = new ArrayList<Integer>();  //int
    private Main game;
    private OrthographicCamera orthographicCamera;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    public static int whichlevel=1;
    private Mario player;
    public Stage stage;
    private Hud hud;
    private TmxMapLoader maploader;
    private TiledMap tilemap;
    static int walks = 0;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private World world;
    private Array<Item> items;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ItemVector> itemstoSpawn;
    String text="";
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    private OtherWorldCreator otherWorldCreator;
    public  String kodas;
    public boolean b =false;


public  MainCodeProgram(){

}
    public MainCodeProgram(Main game, String text,SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        if(text == null){
            textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("All.pack");
            this.game= game;
            orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
            viewport = new FitViewport(Main.Width / Main.PPM, Main.Height / Main.PPM, orthographicCamera);
            viewport.apply();
            hud = new Hud(game.spriteBatch);
            newlevel();
            otherWorldCreator = new OtherWorldCreator(this);
            player = new Mario( this);
             world.setContactListener(new WorldContact());
            items = new Array<Item>();
            itemstoSpawn = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ItemVector>();
        }

        if(text != null){
            b = true;
            textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("All.pack");
            this.game= game;
            orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
            viewport = new FitViewport(Main.Width / Main.PPM, Main.Height / Main.PPM, orthographicCamera);
            viewport.apply();
            hud = new Hud(spriteBatch);
            newlevel();
            otherWorldCreator = new OtherWorldCreator(this);
            player = new Mario( this);
            world.setContactListener(new WorldContact());
            items = new Array<Item>();
            itemstoSpawn = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ItemVector>();
            input(text);

        }

    }

 public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){return textureAtlas;}
    @Override
    public void show() {}
    int i = 0, kur = 1;
    public void handleInput(float dt) {
        if (player.currentstate!= Mario.State.died) {
           ;

        }
    }
    public void spawnItem(ItemVector idef)
    {
        itemstoSpawn.add(idef);
    }
    public void handleSpawningItems(){
        if(!itemstoSpawn.isEmpty())
        {
            ItemVector idef = itemstoSpawn.poll();
            if(idef.type == Mushroom.class){items.add(new Mushroom(this, idef.position.x,idef.position.y));}
        }
    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
       handleInput(dt);
        handleSpawningItems();
        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
        player.update(dt);
        for (Enemy enemy: otherWorldCreator.getEbemies()) {
            enemy.update(dt);
            if(enemy.getX() < player.getX() + 224 / Main.PPM){enemy.b2body.setActive(true);}
        }
        for(Item item : items){item.update(dt);}
        hud.refresh(dt);
        if(player.currentstate!= Mario.State.died){orthographicCamera.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;}
        orthographicCamera.update();
        renderer.setView(orthographicCamera);
    }
    public boolean gameOver()
    {
        if(player.currentstate== Mario.State.died && palyer.getStateTimer() > 3){return true;}
        if(whichlevel== 5){return true;}
        else if(player.getY() <0){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }
    public boolean Youwonn()
    {
        if(whichlevel==4){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        int k = 0;
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        b2dr.render(world, orthographicCamera.combined);
        game.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(orthographicCamera.combined);
        game.spriteBatch.begin();
        game.draw(game.spriteBatch);
        for (Enemy enemy: otherWorldCreator.getEbemies())
            enemy.draw(game.spriteBatch);
        for(Item item : items)
            item.draw(game.spriteBatch);
        game.spriteBatch.end();
        game.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();
        if(gameOver())
        {
            whichlevel= 1;
            game.setScreen(new GameOverWorld(game));
            dispose();
        }
        if ((player.getX() > 15 && whichlevel< 4)) {
            whichlevel++;
            if(whichlevel!=4){
                game.setScreen(new MainCodeProgram(game,"",""));    
                dispose();
            }
        }
        if (whichlevel==4)
        {
            game.setScreen(new WinWindow(game));
            dispose();
        }
        Main.inp1.stage.draw();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {viewport.update(width,height);}
    public World getWorld(){ return world;}
    public TiledMap getMap(){return tilemap;}
    @Override
    public void pause() {}
    @Override
    public void resume() {}
    @Override
    public void hide() {}
    public  void newlevel()
    {
        maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
        if(whichlevel== 1){tilemap = maploader.load("mario1lvl.tmx");
        }
        if (whichlevel== 2){tilemap = maploader.load("mario2lvl.tmx");}
        if (whichlevel== 3){tilemap = maploader.load("mario3lvl.tmx");}
        if (whichlevel== 4){
            game.setScreen(new WinWindow(game));}


            renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tilemap, 1  / Main.PPM);

            orthographicCamera.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10 ), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        tilemap.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();
    }
    public void input(String text) {
        ArrayList<String> pseudocode = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.text = text;
        i = 0;
        String str = text;
        String split[] = str.split("/");
        for (String spacebar : split) {
            pseudocode.add(spacebar);
            i = 0;
        }
        int foras = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < pseudocode.size(); i++) {
            if(pseudocode.get(i).equals("jump")||pseudocode.get(i).equals("jump;")){jump();}   
            if(pseudocode.get(i).startsWith("int")){recognizeint(pseudocode.get(i));}
            if(pseudocode.get(i).startsWith("for"))
            {
                recognizefor(pseudocode.get(i));
                foras++;
            }
            if(pseudocode.get(i).startsWith("while")){ recognizewhile(pseudocode.get(i));}
            if(pseudocode.get(i).endsWith("--")||pseudocode.get(i).endsWith("--;"))
            {
                if(foras == 0){minuminus(pseudocode.get(i));}
                else{foras--;}
            }
            if(pseudocode.get(i).endsWith("++")||pseudocode.get(i).endsWith("++;"))
            {
                if(foras==0){plusplus(pseudocode.get(i));}
                else{foras--;}
            }
            if(istheend){
                walks = 0;
                istheend = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void canceled() {

    }

 public void jump()
    {
        if(istheend){
            try {Thread.sleep(1*walks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        else{try {Thread.sleep(50*walks);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        walks = 0;
        if(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
            if(b == true) {
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);      //Mistake is here
            }
        } 

        else if(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y != 0){
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Mistake is here:

```
public void jump()
    {
        if(istheend){
            try {Thread.sleep(1*walks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        else{try {Thread.sleep(50*walks);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
        walks = 0;
        if(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
            if(b == true) {
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);      //Mistake is here
            }
        } 

        else if(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y != 0){
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code it is a little confusing, for the ApplyLinearImpulse works in your HandleInput you send a command jump() and inside the Entity you make the jump() method and also to make the animation to join the b2body, with update(dt) method + getState() + getFrame().

Your jump() method should be simple like this

```
public void jump(){
if(currentState != State.Jumping){
b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,4f), b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
currentState=State.JUMPING
}
}
```

What should be stuck the applyLinearImpulse are the conditions you included. Try to remove it all and leave only the main stuff. Use also LOGS everywhere `Gdx.app.log("MESSAGE:", "" + variable);` and you can start seeing what is going in and out with your methods and variables, and find your mistake.

Also, if you would like to learn more and don't forget any detail regarding map / viewport / b2bodies, follow this tutorial that I use as my guide for B2Box (Youtube / Github), it is very quick and easy to follow and you are going to love use B2Box for everything :-) and also continue with LibGdx Framework developments.

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt) Youtube Tutorial.

Click [here](https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario) GitHub codes.

I hope it helps you.

Cheers!!